# $\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}+\cos x\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ with one-variable calculus solution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Prove that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}+\cos x\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$

My textbook says that we need to note that the integral can be transformed into $\int_L (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}x+y\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x)\mathrm{d}y)$, where $L: y=\sin x$, $0\leq x\leq\pi$. We denote $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by $P(x,y)$, and  $y\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x)$ by $Q(x,y)$. And then it is not hard to compute $\int_l P\mathrm{d}x+Q\mathrm{d}y$, where $l:(0\leq x\leq\pi\wedge y=0)$, as well as  $\int_{l+L} P\mathrm{d}x+Q\mathrm{d}y$ (by Green's formula), (all the directions here are omitted, but it should make no ambiguity). Hence the question is done. I think this method is hard to observe. **Do we have a way merely apply theorems of one-variable calculus?** I have observed that $\cos x\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x})=\cos x\sin x(2\ln\sin x-\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))$, and $\cos x\sin x\ln\sin x=(\sin x\ln\sin x)(\sin x)'$, hence its indefinite integral is computable. I do not know if this observation would help.

Comment: [Numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2Bsin%28x%29%5E2%29%2Bcos%28x%29*sin%28x%29*log%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%5E2%2Bsin%28x%29%5E2%29%29%2Cx%3D0..Pi%29) it's $\pi^2/2$.

Comment: There are plenty of single-variable integrals that can be evaluated only by using multivariable techniques or complex analytic techniques. There's no reason to think (or even hope) that this problem can be solved as you wish.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fine. Next time I will try to apply other techniques, instead of only using theorems of one-variable calculus.

Comment: The standard example (although I can give you plenty more) is $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the integration by parts, you have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int(\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}+\cos x\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}dx+\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))\mathrm{d}\sin^2x\\
&=&\int\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}dx+\frac12\bigg(\sin^2x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x})-\int\frac{\sin^2x(1+\frac{x+\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}})}{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}}\mathrm{d}x\bigg).
\end{eqnarray}
Now combining these two integrals and simplifying will give the primitive.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice observation!

Answer (score 3):

My earlier comment notwithstanding, Mathematica gives me an answer for the indefinite integral that I am not (yet) able to duplicate by hand or even to check!! You can work on it!

\begin{multline}
\int \left(\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x} + \sin x\cos x\ln\big(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\big)\right)dx = \\-\frac14\sin^2 x + \frac12\left(x\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}+\sin^2x\ln\big(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\big)\right).
\end{multline}

As supporting evidence, it gives $\pi^2/2$ for the value of the definite integral.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}+\cos x\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}))\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x})\mathrm{d}\sin x\\
&=&\int_L\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}x+y\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\mathrm{d}y\\
&=&\int_{L+l}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}x+y\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\mathrm{d}y-\int_l\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}x+y\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\mathrm{d}y.
\end{eqnarray}
Now you can use Green's Theorem to calculate the first term since the second term is easy to handle.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I now understand the solution on my textbook. However I desire a solution merely apply theorem of one-variable calculus, such as the Newton-Leibniz formula and the formula of change of variable (in the one-dimension integral). Do you have ideas on this?